# why can't I call my method from within class in python?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a button class for my game, using pygame. But in the button class, I cannot call methods that are contained in the class itself.

I am new to classes so I may be missing something important, I'm sorry

I tried to add self to the isHovering() Method but it still doesn't work.

```py
import pygame

class Button():
    def __init__(self, pos, value, img, screen):
        self.pos = pos
        self.value = value
        self.img = img
        self.screen = screen

    ### Getters and Setters ###===============
    ### Get/Set Value : True/False ###
    def setValue(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def getValue(self):
        return self.value

    ### Get/Set Pos ###
    def setPos(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos
    def getPos(self):
        return self.pos

    ### Get/Set Img ###
    def setImg(self, img):
        self.img = img
    def getImg(self):
        return self.img

    #==========================================

    def isHovering(self):
        pos = getPos()
        imgRect = pygame.rect(pos[0], pos[1], 105, 105)
        if imgRect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def update(self, screen):
        if isHovering():
            image = pygame.transform.scale(self.img(95, 95))
        else:
            image = pygame.transform.scale(self.img(105, 105))
        screen.blit(image, self.pos)
```

I thought that when update(screen) was called in my main loop, that it would call isHovering(), and return a True or False, but instead I get this error:

NameError: name 'isHovering' is not defined

Comment: You have to use `self.isHovering()` because you are dealing with an instance of the class and the instance has no idea who it is unless you say "me!" by using `self`

Comment: If you are familiar with Java or some other language, this is a place where Python is somewhat unique.  Python doesn't "guess" that you want to call another method on the object you are in.  You have to say that's what you want explicitly with 'self', as @Astrocow says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `def update(self, screen)`,
The if statement should be `if self.isHovering()`.

If not, the interpreter will look for a `isHovering` function somewhere in the current module, like if you had defined it outside your class.
Using the `self.` prefix will indicate that you are indeed trying to call a method of the instance as JacoblRR already pointed out in a comment.